# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work for .began state

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I've added two gesture recognizers to my `UIView`:

```
func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.state == .began {
        print("snapping photo")
    }

}
func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        print("snapping video")
    }
}
```

When both are set to `state == .began`, only `longPress` fires. When I set tap to `.ended`, both fire.

Why doesn't tap work when its state is set to `.began`?

Comment: I'm guessing UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't have a began state, and I should use touchesBegan if I care, but the docs don't say anything about it:

Although taps are discrete gestures, they are discrete for each state of the gesture recognizer; thus the associated action message is sent when the gesture begins and is sent for each intermediate state until (and including) the ending state of the gesture. Code that handles tap gestures should therefore test for the state of the gesture.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Handling UIKit Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures) tells us:

> Gesture recognizers come in two types: discrete and continuous. A *discrete gesture recognizer* calls your action method exactly once after the gesture is recognized. After its initial recognition criteria are met, a *continuous gesture recognizer* performs calls your action method many times, notifying you whenever the information in the gesture’s event changes.
>
> ...
>
> The [`state`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1619998-state) property of a gesture recognizer communicates the object’s current state of recognition. For continuous gestures, the gesture recognizer updates the value of this property from [`.began`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state/began) to [`.changed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state/changed) to [`.ended`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state/ended), or to [`.cancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/state/cancelled). Your action methods use this property to determine an appropriate course of action.

The `UITapGestureRecognizer` is a discrete gesture, and as such, your event handler is called once when the gesture was recognized.
In practice, this means that your tap gesture recognizer handler will not be called for a state of `.began`. It is, however, called for a state of `.ended`.

(The [Handling UIKit Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures) documentation tells us that the handler of a discrete gesture will be called “exactly once”. This is consistent with my experience. Confusingly, the [tap gesture documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) and the [Handling Tap Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_tap_gestures) reference suggest that one should test for a state of `.ended` even though, in practice, that’s the only state for which your tap gesture handler will ever be called. Regardless, while it might be prudent to look for a state of `.ended`, don’t ever expect to ever see a state of `.began` in your discrete gesture handlers.)

The `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, on the other hand, is a continuous gesture, so checking the state is very useful (determining when the gesture `.began`, `.changed`, `.ended`, etc.). That's why you see it called for the `state` of `.began`.

Comment: Thanks, I had been reading the [UITapGestureRecognizer doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer) which recommends you do check state, but your link lays out the discrete/continuous distinction more clearly.