# Adding a gesture recognizer to an image view in a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I add a Gesture Recognizer to a `UIImageView` in a table cell? I want it so that if a user taps an image in the cell, the image will change and the data model will update.

I know this needs to be set up in the `UITableViewController`. My code currently can execute a command if anywhere in the cell is tapped, but I would like it to execute only if the image is tapped, not anywhere in the cell.

I setup up the gesture recognizer in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load sample data
    loadSampleHabits()

    // Initialize tap gesture recognizer
    var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapEdit(recognizer:)))
    // Add gesture recognizer to the view
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

And this is the function

```
//action method for gesture recognizer
func tapEdit(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) {
            if let tappedCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tapIndexPath) as? HabitTableViewCell {
                print("Row Selected")

            }
        }
    }
```

[image: What the cell looks like]

As a secondary question, are there any conflicts if I want to add a gesture recognizer to the cell and the image view within the cell?

Comment: You can try removing  if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended condition from your method. Check my ans.

Comment: @b.gibson: I would adapt to luckyShubhra's answer. I also used the same somewhere in one of my projects and did not face any issue

Comment: If you're going to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` on image view, you don't need to check the `state`. That's really only relevant for continuous gestures (like long press or pan gestures). But just using a button with an image (like [iOS Dev suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45049086/1271826)) makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 17):

You are adding gesture recognizer on your tableview instead of imageView as you required. Yo need to move your code from viewDidLoad to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add gesture to  imageView in each cell while configuing your cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
     var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapEdit(recognizer:)))
     // Add gesture recognizer to your image view
     cell.yourimageview.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

Note: Do make sure to enable `userinteraction` of your image view

```
cell.yourimageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

For your requirement I will suggest using UILongPressGestureRecognizer as it has less chances of conflict in gesture and didselect. Yo can add UILongPressGestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad and access it as per your requirement.

```
let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

Define method as

```
func handleLongPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
if gesture.state != .began { return }
let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: self.tableView)
    if let tapIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: tapLocation) {
        if let tappedCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: tapIndexPath) as? HabitTableViewCell {
            print("Row Selected")

        }
}
```

You can try removing  `if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended` condition from your method.

UITapGestureRecognizer is a discrete gesture, and as such, your event handler is called only once when the gesture was recognized. You don't have to check the state at all. Certainly you won't receive a call for the state of .Began. For more info consider @Rob ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763997/utapgesturerecognizer-doesnt-work-for-began-state).

Comment: was in the similar position to add a tap like gesture on UIimage in a cell, a good hack is to minimise the `lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.01` to replicate a tap

Comment: It works very well ! I create a Radio Button Group, that swift eliminate for no reason ! I added a tap ( two different for each image (circle and largecircle.fill.circle) in two UIImageView. The #selector function interchange the image of the two UIImageView and update the NSManagedObject linked to the state of the Radio Button Group. the function : func tapEdit(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)  did the trick! They use the same function that swap the state of the buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add This line in cell for row at index path

```
     var recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapEdit(recognizer:)))
        // Add gesture recognizer to the view
        cell.yourimageviewname.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

cell.yourimageviewname.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: change cell.youtimageviewname.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 4):

I have had design a solution like this. I just write a sample code below:

```
import UIKit

protocol CellImageTapDelegate {
    func tableCell(didClickedImageOf tableCell: UITableViewCell)
}

class SampleCell : UITableViewCell {

    var delegate : CellImageTapDelegate?
    var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        tapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SampleCell.imageTapped(gestureRecgonizer:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func imageTapped(gestureRecgonizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.tableCell(didClickedImageOf: self)
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController, CellImageTapDelegate {

    // CellImageTapDelegate
    func tableCell(didClickedImageOf tableCell: UITableViewCell) {
        if let rowIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: tableCell) {
            print("Row Selected of indexPath: \(rowIndexPath)")
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SampleCellID", for: indexPath) as! SampleCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

remember to do following in storyboard
1. enable user interaction of imageview
[image: 1. enable user interaction of imageview]
2. set class of tableviewcell
[image: 2. set class of tableviewcell]
3. set reuse identifier of tableviewcell
[image: 3. set reuse identifier of tableviewcell]

Comment: tested project for this solution. [zip project on google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B70RpDc-VWUuSVA0NEFnRldfSE0)

Comment: It only detects if the cell is clicked, but the gesture recognizer is not attached to any control, for example an UIImageView or a UIButton .

Answer (score 3):

For my suggestion you have to use `UIButton` in cell, for performance 
improvements,

**UIButtons**

Specially designed for this and have been extensively optimized by Apple for touches.

If you want image in cell you can use `UIButton` with Image inside.

Answer (score 3):

```
// create an instance of UITapGestureRecognizer and tell it to run 
// an action we'll call "handleTap:"
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
// we use our delegate
tap.delegate = self
// allow for user interaction
cell.imageViewName.userInteractionEnabled = true
// add tap as a gestureRecognizer to tapView
cell.imageViewName.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class UserInfoCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePlaceholder: UIImageView!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 1


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserInfoCell" ,for: indexPath ) as! UserInfoCell
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.openGallery))

            cell.imagePlaceholder.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            cell.imagePlaceholder.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.name.text = "Akshay"

            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedImage") {
                cell.imagePlaceholder.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
            }

            return cell




    }
    @objc func openGallery(){
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker,animated:  true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let userimage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        let imageData = userimage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(imageData, forKey: "savedImage")
        print("image found")
        self.imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    }
}
```

*This code select image from gallery using Tapgesture of ImageView inside a TableViewCell*